# Assignment Branch Condition too high

Tags: ruby, coding-style, rubocop

I have a simple class that, on initialization, takes between one and eight parameters. It sets the accessors to these to use later. Rubocop is trying to arrest me for the ABC being too high, but I'm not sure if there's actually anything wrong with what I've done. Is this a case where I just disable the inspection on my initialize?

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :one, :two, :three, :four
  attr_accessor :five, :six, :seven, :eight

  def initialize(p={})
    @one = p[:one] if p[:one].present?
    # ...
    @eight = p[:eight] if p[:eight].present?
  end
end
```

My only thought on reducing size would be to do something like iterating through all my attr_accessors on initialize, seeing if there is a corresponding symbol passed through in the has, and if so assigning it.

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :one, :two, :three, :four
  attr_accessor :five, :six, :seven, :eight

  def initialize(p={})
    instance_variables.each do |variable|
      send("@#{variable}") = p["#{send(variable)}".to_sym] if p["#{send(variable)}".to_sym].present?
    end
  end
end
```

But this seems kind of weak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one of the ways to achieve what you are trying to do:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor(*%i[one two three four five six seven eight])

  def initialize(p = {})
    p.keys.each { |k| instance_variable_set("@#{k}", p.fetch(k, nil)) }
  end
end
```

Check out for [Hash#`fetch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) method.

You can also use it to just access the key-value pairs of `p` variable, if you instead of 8 variables decide to go with one (`@p`)

---

## EDIT

Just out of curiosity wrote this version (some meta programming used) - it will dynamically add `attr_accessor` for added instance variables:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(p = {})
    p.keys.each do |k|
      instance_variable_set("@#{k}", p.fetch(k, nil))
      self.class.__send__(:attr_accessor, k)
    end
  end
end
```

What is happening, is we take provided to `initialize` method argument (hash `p`), get its keys and create instance variables from them, assigning each variable with value corresponding to the key. Then we're defining `attr_accessor` for each of the keys.

```
a = Foo.new(a: 2, b: 3)
#=> #<Foo:0x00000002d63ad8 @a=2, @b=3>
```

Comment: This looks similar to what I was thinking might be a cop out. Pun intended. While I agree this is a way to solve the problem, is there a reference you could point me to so I can read more about why this is the 'right' way? Thanks for taking the time to respond!

Comment: @CarlyL Regarding the right way - Ruby is very flexible language, so things can be done in various of ways. And often the "right way" is a matter of personal preferences. I think you can read through Ruby Style Guides to see what **not** to do, but I doubt someone will claim something to be 100% right :)

Comment: You could also put the names of the attributes in a frozen array, like ```ATTR_NAMES = %i(one two three four five six seven eight).freeze``` constant and call ```attr_accessor(*ATTR_NAMES)```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't assign each of those as different variables. You should rather save that to a variable as a single hash, and access the hash when you need the values. In fact, you already seem to have a variable `p`. So keep that as `@p = p`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. Both responses kind of say that I can just have one attr_accessor p which is a hash, but that seems kind of strange to me. Do you have any reference I can read as to why this would be the best way?